# SCSS Interpolation not working

Tags: variables, for-loop, sass, interpolation

I've used sass interpolation before and I can't for the life of me figure out why target data attributes won't compile. It has to be related to the quotes...I've tried double, single, adding @charset 'UTF-8'; to app.scss (which was a long shot).

Any ideas?! I bet it's something stupid. Note, how the class .test comes through fine.

```
@mixin grid-column {
@media #{$small-up} {
    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        .test { width: #{$i}; }
        &[data-small="#{$i}"] { width: grid-calc($i, $column-count); }
        }
    }
@media #{$medium-up} {
    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        &[data-medium="#{$i}"] { width: grid-calc($i, $column-count); }
        }
    }
@media #{$large-up} {
    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        &[data-large='#{$i}'] { width: grid-calc($i, $column-count); }
        }
    }       
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.row .column .test {
  width: 1; }
.row .column[data-small="#{$i}"] {
  width: 8.33333%; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Eh, I figured it out. It was because I was using libsass. :P